# "Will you close the door" vs "Could you close the door"

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

I enter in a small bookstore, the owner tells me:

> "**Will** you close the door please?!"

I enter in a small bookstore, I ask the owner:

> "**Shall** I close the door?"

The two phrases above in brackets should be correct.

Is it still correct/common in English to say:

> "**Could** you close the door, please?!"
>
> "**Should** I close the door?"

If yes, what's the difference between the two? (If there is any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two examples are correct for both being told and asking.
The two sentences that you are questioning are also correct.

For this AmE speaker there is a subtle difference between **will you** and **would you**, and **shall I** and **should I**.

> **Will you** please

implies an immediacy, **do it now**

> **Would you** please

is asking you to do something

> if you **are able to**
>   if it's not too **inconvenient**
>   if you **have the time**
>   if it's **not too much trouble**

it is **more polite**.

**Shall I** is posing a question by **offering to do something** and looking for **mutual agreement** for that action.

> **Shall I** make tea?
>   **Shall I** fetch you at 4?

**Should I** is asking for guidance of an action based on **a rule** or **opinion**: **should** or **should not** do.

> **Should I** go to the dentist when I have a toothache?
>   **Should I** discipline my dog if he misbehaves?
>   **Should I** take out the garbage on Mondays?

From my experience, **should** is more AmE and **shall** is more BrE.

> **Could you** *do something*

Is asking if you **are able to** perform an action and is related to **can you** but is more **conditional** in the way that **asking for permission** is

> **Could** you get me a glass of water please?
>   **Could** you stand on your head?
>   **Could** you expand on this?

an answer might be

> I **could** do that *(for you)* if I wanted to, but I **won't**

meaning: I am **able** to do what your request, but I **don't feel like it**

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with "Could" in place of "Would". Could you expand on this too? Please don't delete what you explained about using "would", it's interesting too.

Comment: **Shall** I add additional commentary to include **could**, and you think that I **should** keep my previous remarks there? Gladly. If you **would** take a look at my edits, it **should** help clarify your understanding.

Comment: Do you think that "Will you please..." could sound kind of rude expecially in an email text when writing to a customer?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio Personally as an AmE speaker, I would use **Would you please**...", nothing wrong with **Will you please**... but could be interpreted as coming from a non-native speaker depending on what follows